# JQuery plugin/script is not working on ASP.NET MVC 5 view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently struggling to get any of these jQuery plugins to work correctly with the views that I generated. I've tried to bundle the js/css as seen below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
```

-->                        "~/Scripts/jquery.share.js"));

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery.share.css"));
```

Here is the HTML and JavaScript itself.

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mydiv').share({
        networks: ['facebook', 'pinterest', 'googleplus', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'tumblr', 'email', 'stumbleupon', 'digg'],
        orientation: 'vertical',
        urlToShare: 'http://www.example.com',
        affix: 'left center'
    });
    </script>
</pre>


<div id="mydiv" class="share-affix" style="left: auto; top: 40%;">
    <a class="pop share-icon-twitter" title="Share this page on Twitter" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>
    <a class="pop share-icon-facebook" title="Share this page on Facebook" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>
    <a class="pop share-icon-pinterest" title="Share this page on Pinterest" href="#"></a>
    <a class="pop share-icon-googleplus" title="Share this page on GooglePlus" href="#"></a>
    <a class="pop share-icon-linkedin" title="Share this page on LinkedIn" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>
    <a class="pop share-icon-tumblr" title="Share this page on Tumblr" href="#" style="display: block;"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include this line into your page.

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css/")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Should I reference @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") at the top of the page between the razor @{ } brackets or in the <head></head> same goes for the Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") Maybe, they're not initializing in the right area of the web page.

Comment: @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") in head and @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") at the bottom of the page. You should also wrap your script with $(document).ready(function(){//your code.});